# Removing elements by index in vector pairs

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

I have vector pairs of integers both on first and second position and the input is rather specific.
Firstly, I have i inputs that all go into the first spots of the vector, but afterwards comes the second array of inputs that's supposed to go to the second position.
However, what I'd like to do, is I have a condition that if I find an input of the second spot bigger than a certain value (`mana`, in my case the variable), I'd like to simply not put it into the vector pair, and remove the first element on that index from the first position and I'm having trouble figuring out how to code it.
Here's the part of that code:

```
vector<pair<int, int>>spellOne;

for (int i = 0; i < nSpellOne; i++)
{
    scanf_s("%d", &input);
    spellOne.back().first = input;
}

for (int i = 0; i < nSpellOne; i++)
{
    scanf_s("%d", &input);

    if (input > mana)
    {
        // removing the element on .first position at i index
    }
    else
    {
        spellOne.at(i).second = input;
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me out on how to do that and if that's even possible, or should I switch to a different type of arrays?
I also considered using maps, but that wasn't possible, since there's a high chance I get the same value twice in either first/second spot in the vector, hence I can't use any of them as a key.

Comment: You need to delete the whole pair at index `i`, but then decrease `i` by one too (careful not to give a negative value to `i` though)

Comment: I tried doing that with the erase function for vectors, but I get an error as I need to specify either the first or second position, and when I build the program to erase spellOne.erase(spellOne.begin() + i), the program crashes, saying vector iterator offset out of range.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense Sara, check my example that I posted as an answer, should be enough to get you boosted! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made an example, which should get you boosted to complete your task. In my example bellow I populate the vector and then erase the pairs that have a second value greater than a certain threshold (2 in this case).

Now you can use two variables to keep track of the loop that erases the elements, one to loop through the whole vector and one to keep track of the current index to be checked; if we remove `v[3]`, then the next element `v[4]` is shifted (because we called `erase()`) in place of `v[3]`, thus we should examine index 3 again!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    vector< pair<int, int> > v;
    int N = 5;
    const int threshold = 2;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        v.push_back(make_pair(i, i));

    int i = 0;
    while(i < v.size())
        if (v[i].second > threshold)
            v.erase(v.begin() + i);
        else
            i++;

    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        cout << "(" << v[i].first << ", " << v[i].second << ")\n";

    cout << "Done" << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
Done
```

---

Edit for your comment: You could try that:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < nSpellOne.size())
{
    scanf_s("%d", &input);
    if (input > mana)
        nSpellOne.erase(nSpellOne.begin() + i);
    else
        i++;
}
```

PS - When writing efficient code, don't bother for whether `std::cin` or `scanf()` is faster, focus on your algorithm!

Comment: Agh, I was secretly hoping there'd be an efficient solution to just remove the element on the spot, but this also works better than what I previously had, just looping through the entire thing. Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: @Sara when the input arrives, you don't know which pair you need to delete if the condition is met, thus you have to loop over the vector or call `std::find()` which will be probably be as efficient as my solution. You are welcome and thanks for the nice question! =)

Comment: I suppose I just figured the `i` would work as the way to find the element, since the first set of input is the same length as the second one, hence they'd be at the same position, but I overlooked the fact that `erase()` moves the elements backwards.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code for loading up the vector isn't entirely correct.

```
vector<pair<int, int>>spellOne;

for (int i = 0; i < nSpellOne; i++)
{
    int input1, input2;
    //scanf is C! Prefer C++ for doing input
    if(std::cin >> input1 >> input2)
        //Simply calling .back() presumes that an element already exists there, which in
        //the code you've provided, this isn't the case. emplace_back will allocate the 
        //memory correctly.
        spellOne.emplace_back(input1, input2);
    else
        break;//Could also do error handling here
}
```

`std::vector`'s don't just magically have space for whichever elements you query: you have to specifically use the methods that insert elements into the vector, whether it be `emplace_back` (ideal), `emplace`, `push_back`, or `insert`. `back` only requests the back-most element, and will have bad results if the element in question doesn't exist, or if you're expecting it to return a unique element per call.

Then, when iterating through the vector, proper use of the STL will simplify things greatly.

```
auto it = std::remove_if(
    spellOne.begin(),
    spellOne.end(),
    [mana](std::pair<int, int> const& data) {
        if(data.second > mana) return true;
        else return false;
    }
);

spellOne.erase(it, spellOne.end());
```

This code does make a small change to your use case, where we're supplying the second number at the same time as the first number. So the input to this program will be `1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 10 10`. If you really need your previous order (though I don't recommend it) this code will work fine, though will be slower.

```
vector<pair<int, int>>spellOne;

for (int i = 0; i < nSpellOne; i++)
{
    int input;
    if(std::cin >> input)
        spellOne.emplace_back(input, 0);
    else
        break;
}

for(std::pair<int, int> & data : spellOne) {
    int input;
    if(std::cin >> input)
        data.second = input;
    else
        break;
}

auto it = std::remove_if(
    spellOne.begin(),
    spellOne.end(),
    [mana](std::pair<int, int> const& data) {
        if(data.second > mana) return true;
        else return false;
    }
);

spellOne.erase(it, spellOne.end());
```

Comment: This is actually a wonderful solution, I'll consider merging it with the other answer and it explained something I hadn't considered about vectors very clearly. Also, I'd been told recently that the scanf function is apparently a bit quicker than std::cin, but I suppose that was a lie, judging by your answer, haha. Thank you!

Comment: @Sara `scanf` might very well be faster than `std::cin` (though I've seen no evidence that it amounts to significant savings in real-world applications), but `std::cin` offers a wide variety of error-checking mechanisms that `scanf` glosses over. The benefit here isn't so much about speed as it's about making sure that your program behaves responsibly when the user does something unexpected (like, for example, providing a non-numeric input).

Comment: Alright, the `emplace_back` function works like a charm, I got it working beautifully, I've never even considered it, so thanks!